# full SRTM1 arc second download

Tags: srtm

I would like to download the new released maps (2014) SRTM1 but where can we find them? Is there an FTP server to download the whole images?

Comment: These types of question can be easily answered by searching. Google is your friend here.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=srtm1+2014+download

Comment: https://thepiratebay.org/torrent/26740167/SRTM_(Shuttle_Radar_Topography_Mission)_Global_30m_(SRTMGL1) is what I used, but it's not a trusted source.

Answer (score 2):

The USGS is hosting near global SRTM1

http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/

I believe it's not void filled though.